# python bind to interface and port on windows

Tags: python, sockets, multicast

My computer having 2 NICs: one with 1.1.1.1 while the other with some internal network.

I've some strange behavior while binding to ip and port:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('1.1.1.1',1234))
sock.settimeout(0)

group= socket.inet_aton('224.1.1.1')
mreq = struct.pack('4sL', group, socket.INADDR_ANY)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)
print("Listening at:" + str(sock.getsockname()))

time.sleep(2)
while True:
    print("\waiting to receive message")
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(1024)

    print ("received {} butes from {}".format(len(data), adsress))
    print (data)
```

On `print("Listening at:" + str(sock.getsockname()))` I'm getting the expected data (i.e interface 1.1.1.1 and port 1234).
On `print ("received {} butes from {}".format(len(data), adsress))` I'm getting data from other interface

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Is your host configured to act as a router? `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1` if so that could just be the TCP/IP stack determining the best path for you. What does your route table look like?

Comment: This is Windows, not Linux. And no, this is not a router, but a standard development PC.